# How to have my PHP script make images square, while maintaining their original ratio?

Tags: php, image

I have been developing my website for some time now, and I am looking to make it even better with one small detail. Currently, when a user creates and account, they can view their "My Page" and do all sorts of things, including change their profile picture from the default one I have provided, to whatever they want. Unfortunately, if they were to upload an image with a ratio of anything greater than or less than 1:1, i.e. 300x200, then my script will re-size it to fit the avatar form, but it keeps the ratio, and makes the image float to the top of the box. Here is an image of an avatar that does not have a 1:1 ratio:
[image]

As you can see, the image is as I describe it above. The only time it makes a perfect square is when the image that the user uploads has a 1:1 ratio. Here is an example:
[image]

Obviously, it is unreasonable to expect that a user will always upload a 1:1 image. So what I am looking for is someone to help me tweak my script, which I will provide, so that on all avatar uploads, even if the image has a 1:1 ratio, will pretty much mount the image into a black "canvas", for lack of better wording, and center the image on that canvas both vertically and horizontally. Here is what I mean, using an image that I edited in Photoshop to give it the black canvas:

[image]

As you can see, the profile picture in this last image is exactly what I need my script to do. I will provide my script:

PHP

```
<?php 
if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
$fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
$kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileExt = end($kaboom);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: That image has no dimensions");
    exit(); 
}
$db_file_name = rand(100000000000,999999999999).".".$fileExt;
if($fileSize > 2048576) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: Your image file was larger than 2MB");
    exit(); 
} else if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: Your image file was not jpg, gif or png     type");
    exit();
} else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: An unknown error occurred");
    exit();
}
$sql = "SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$avatar = $row[0];
if($avatar != ""){
    $picurl = "../user/$log_username/$avatar"; 
    if (file_exists($picurl)) { unlink($picurl); }
}
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../user/$log_username/$db_file_name");
if ($moveResult != true) {
    header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: File upload failed");
    exit();
}
include_once("../php_includes/image_resize.php");
$target_file = "../user/$log_username/$db_file_name";
$resized_file = "../user/$log_username/$db_file_name";
$wmax = 200;
$hmax = 300;
img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
$sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar='$db_file_name' WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
mysqli_close($db_conx);
header("location: ../user.php?u=$log_username");
exit();
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do this on the front end? Put your avatar photos in a DIV with a black background and vertically center? In your first example, the background wouldn't be black around those 2 pieces of paper unless the user uploaded a png or gif with transparency.

Comment: That is a good idea, however, if you noticed the circular thumbnail image at the top of the menu bar on the left hand side next to the green username, when the image has an odd ratio, not 1:1, that thumbnail becomes distorted, and maintains the ratio of the original image, and in the case of the car with a 300x200 ratio, it becomes and oval, not a circle. @GrahamT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the image as a background instead of an img tag, then you can position it center.

```
<div class="avatar"></div>

.avatar {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image: url("avatar.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
border-radius: 50%; // If you want it to be a circle
}
```

Comment: Since I couldn't fond anything else, this will definitely work for me. I will have to tweak and teak again, but this answer makes perfect sense, and I appreciate it.